# I want to call the function when script found string "art" - How to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if ($("div:contains('art')" = true)) {
    alert("Test");
};
```

Hello, I have this code, but it doesn't work... How to fix it? I want to call the function when script found string "art" - How to do it?

Comment: are you looking for a `div` with id or class named `art`?

Comment: change = to == and you should be through

Comment: `"div:contains('art')" = true` tries to assign `true` to a string literal... this can never work, it's a syntax error.

Comment: @Satya: Well, that would be `false` all the time, since the string is not equal to `1` (type coercion, long story). I don't know if jQuery will complain about `$(false)` as result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery selector return elements or no elements, so you should check if 1 or more matching elements are found, this should work

```
if ($("div:contains('art')").length > 0) {
   alert("Test");
};
```

Comment: Almost choked laughing because of this alert message

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($("div:contains('art')").length) {
    alert("Art!");
};
```

That is the fix. Your code would not work, because it has incorrect syntax.